# Growing spurt branches of a plum tree

Tags: fruit-trees

I have had my plum tree for 4yrs now, it has never bared fruit, i do have weak looking young branches that are shooting out all over. I had them last year so cut them off but they have grown again this year, so far i have left them but are growing very fast, I am wondering if this is why i am not getting any fruit or i am not pruning properly.

Comment: You say they at shooting out all over. Are they coming off the tree near the ground, or from the upper branches? This will make a difference.

Comment: Welcome! You wouldn't have a few pictures for us, would you?

Comment: And some clue as to where you are in the world would be useful too....

Comment: Also, what time of year are you pruning the tree?

Comment: Please send as many pictures as you are able to include the environment, how it is planted and how you are pruning this tree.  Do you have the correct botanical name?  How much sun does it get?  Is it planted in your lawn and receiving lawn fertilizer???

Comment: http://r.search.yahoo.com/_ylt=AwrTHRTqYZxVx1sAaTRXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTEycjJhZDk0BGNvbG8DZ3ExBHBvcwMzBHZ0aWQDQjAxNjJfMQRzZWMDc3I-/RV=2/RE=1436340842/RO=10/RU=http%3a%2f%2fforestry.about.com%2fod%2ftreeandforestcare%2fss%2fsucker_sprout.htm/RK=0/RS=PWaNEk9L7mS5vxlLsEiakVoUW40- Try this link about the suckers/pruning...